# How do i unit test a function that has document.querySelector?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

```
export function getNavHeight() {
  const merchantNav = document.getElementById(
    'merchant-header-main-wrapper-internal'
  )
  const dw2Nav = document.querySelector('.cw_navbar__mainnav')
  let navHeight = 72 // Consumer header is fixed to 72
  if (merchantNav) {
    navHeight = merchantNav.offsetHeight
  }
  if (dw2Nav) {
    navHeight = dw2Nav.offsetHeight
  }
  return navHeight
}
```

The above block is the function I want to write a unit tests for, we are using Jest and our app is mostly written in React. This function is used because we have some other client-side scripts that get called to render different Navs, so we are using this function to determine Nav Height.
What is the best way to test this? I am new to testing so any help would be much appreciated.

I am confused about how to create a "Fake Dom" and insert different Navs with a different className in order to test the result

Answer (score 1):

You just need to [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks) `document.querySelector`.